# Laravel 4 Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 2 tables:

```
`tasks {id, task_name, status_id}`
`statuses {id, status_name }`
```

A task can only have one status at a time eg Pending, Active, Completed, Aborted, etc

This is what I have so far.

```
class Task extends Eloquent
{
    public function status
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Status', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I try `$task->status->status_name`,  I get 'Trying to get a property of non object' error!

My Status class looks like this

```
class Status extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'statuses';
}
```

Could you explain why I'm having this error?

Comment: You have too many unconnected snippets of code to answer this properly but as the error describes, you're accessing properties incorrectly. For example, things are quite often declared as static with eloquent, so you would need to use :: instead of ->

Comment: What do you mean by " You have too many unconnected
snippets of code to answer this
properly "? Also I don't think changing to a static function would change anything!

Comment: better code formating and improving end question

Comment: For example, while it's clear that $task represents your eloquent model, the way the model is instantiated (or isn't) makes a difference to how you access it. I'm also not a laravel expert by any means, but that's precisely why your filling in some of the gaps would help us help you :) Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got the foreign key in `Task` table, you can use `belongsTo` and Eloquent will look for column `status_id` in `tasks` table for you.

```
public function status
{
 return $this->belongsTo('Status');
}
```

for more information http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent in **One to One** section

For the error `Trying to get a property of non object`
Please make sure there is a value in column `status_id` on table `tasks` on very record.